# Which FOSS licenses permit binary distribution within for-sale products?

Tags: open-source, licensing

Suppose your for-sale software product uses some free open-source library at runtime.  Therefore, you need to distribute the FOSS product in the unchanged, binary form with your product.  Which open-source license permits such distribution and under what conditions?  I'm particularly interested in three licenses:

1. Apache 2
2. MS-PL
3. MIT

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above three licenses all permit such distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume most licenses allow you to distribute the product in binary form. If binary distribution were not allowed it would force every user of the library, and therefore every user of any program that uses the library, to compile it themselves. This would be very impractical.

Usually you just have to provide a way to get the sources for anybody who cares. If you made no changes to the libraries this might be as simple as referring them to the original libraries web page.

That being said, I'm not particularly familiar with the licenses you mention, so you might have to read through them to see what they have to say about binary distribution. It could, for example, be that they require a disclaimer in the binary distribution that states which libraries under that license were used.